# Getting value using attribute in xml php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the value of **result** attribute which is **1** in from the code below.

```
$file  = file_get_contents('https://test.com/...'); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file)

var_dump($xml);
```

gives following object

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
[0]=> string(141) "
    <response result="1"> 
       <message>Yes here</message>
    </response>"
 }
```

How will I be able to get the value of attribute **result = '1'**.

```
print_r($xml->response['result'];  //gives NULL
```

Comment: It might sound kinda dumb but, why dont you return the [0] string as a whole and then preg_match the double quots ("") and return the value that is inside of them? I know its not Ideal, but it works.

Comment: you could use something like [this](https://3v4l.org/sEkVf)

Comment: @berend; casting to an array is preferred `$xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($file);`, instead of `json_decode(json_encode())`

Comment: You need to provide the original XML, from the var_dump() it looks like it is an XML document with another XML document in a text node. If the is the case you will have to read the text value and parse/load it as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`attributes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
$file  = <<<XML
<response result="1">
    <message>Yes here</message>
</response>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

echo $xml->attributes()[0]; # returns '1'
```

If there is only one attribute, the `[0]` can be dropped. If there is more than one, use `[k]` for the (k+1)-th attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `attributes` method after you specified the tag name to get all the attributes of that tag. Then you can get the value of your desired attribute by specifying the attribute name.

```
$xml->response->attributes()['result']
```